# Find $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{f}{g}\right)(x)$ when $x = 2 $

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> > known : $\dfrac{df(x)}{dx} = 3$ when $x = 2$.
> >
> > $\dfrac{dg(x)}{dx} = 4$ when $x = 2$.
> >
> > $\dfrac{d}{dx}(f(x)\cdot g(x)) = 11$ when $x = 2$.
> >
> > $d\left(f^2(x) + g^2(x)\right) = 20$ when $x = 2$. Find $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{f}{g}\right)(x)$ when $x = 2 $

$f'(2) = 3$

$g'(2) = 4$

$(f(2)\cdot g(2))'=11$

$\left(f(2)^2 + g(2)^2\right)' = 20$

Find $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{f}{g}\right)(x)$ when $x = 2 $

$y = \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \rightarrow y' = \frac{f'(x) \cdot g(x) - g'(x)\cdot f(x)}{{g(x)}^2}$

$\left(\dfrac{f(2)}{g(2)}\right)' =\dfrac{ f'(2)g(2) - g'(2)f(2)}{g(2)^2}$

$\left(f(2)^2 + g(2)^2\right)' = 20$

$2f(2)' + 2g(2)' = 20$

But how to find $g(x)$ and $f(x)$? please help me, thanks in advanced

Comment: I think there is a problem of notations: it is known that $(f\circ g)'(2)=11$. This is different from $f'(g(2))$. Precisely, by the Chain rule, the former is equal to $f'(g(2))g'(2)$. Also, $(f(2)^2+g(2)^2)'$ is usually interpreted as the derivative of a number, so is equal to $0$.

Comment: Please state the entire question at the beginning of your post.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{d}{dx} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{f'(x)g(x)-g'(x)f(x)}{(g(x))^2}$

Now let's find the unknown. For $\left(f(x)\cdot g(x)\right)'$
$$(f(x)\cdot g(x))' = f'(x)g(x)+g'(x)f(x)$$
Plug $x=2$
$$f'(2)g(2)+g'(2)f(2)=11\\
4f(2)+3g(2) = 11 \text{ ... (1)}$$

For $\left( (f(x))^2 +(g(x))^2 \right)$
$$\begin{aligned}
\left((f(x))^2+(g(x))^2\right)'&=2f(x)f'(x)+2g(x)g'(x)
\end{aligned}$$

Plug $x=2$
$$2f(x)f'(x)+2g(x)g'(x)=20\\
3f(2)+4g(2)=10 \text{ ... (2)}$$

Solve for $(1) \text{ and }(2)$
$$f(2) = 2 \text{ and } g(2) = 1$$

Ergo

$$\frac{f'(2)g(2)-g'(2)f(2)}{(g(2))^2}=\frac{3-8}{1}=-5$$

Answer (score 0):

We are given that

- $f'(2)=3$
- $g'(2)=4$
- $[f(x)g(x))]'_{x=2}=f'(2)g(2)+f(2)g'(2)=11\implies 4f(2)+3g(2)=11$
- $[f(x)^2+g(x)^2]'_{x=2}=2f(2)f'(2)+2g(2)g'(2)=20\implies3f(2)+4g(2)=10$.

Solving simultaneously yields $f(2)=2$ and $g(2)=1$. Thus \begin{align}\left[\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right]'_{x=2}&=\frac{f'(2)g(2)-f(2)g'(2)}{g(2)^2}=\frac{3\cdot1-2\cdot4}{1^2}=-5.\end{align}

Comment: I have edited the question. There was mistake before

Comment: The question hasn't changed. Please do not remove incorrect attempts, they show that you have attempted the question first before asking.

Comment: Sorry. It wasnt f(g(x)) instead (f.g)(x)